# How to parse image from mp3 file in Android platform

Tags: android

I'm trying to write a media player on my android phone.

There is a function that showing the song's image which embedded in the mp3 file.

Now I have the string of the mp3 file location, so how can I get the image, so I can give it to ImageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into the [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) class to get all the data from the ID3 tag of the mp3 file.

And more specifically, look for the `getEmbeddedPicture` method.

You'll need to use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` to get the actual image.

Comment: Yes, thank u, that's what I want and I have implemented this function by using your method.